# Rails 7 - CurrentAttributes undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, broadcast, turbolinks, ruby-on-rails-7, turbo

Can someone explain me why:

```
 after_commit :send_partial_

 def send_partial_
  
   broadcast_update_to( ... locals:users_in_room_list )

 end
 

 def users_in_room_list

  user = User.find_by(id:Current.user.id)  // return undefined method `id' for 
  nil:NilClass

  user_name =  User.find_by(Current.user) // return <User:0x00007fbecc0dcf40>

 end
```

Why I get `undefined method 'id' for nil:NilClass` for `user` but I get correct data for `user_name` ??

Comment: `User.find_by(nil)` returns the first user. Your `Current.user` is `nil`. Your approach won't work since you probably set up the `CurrentAttributes` in a controller, but `broadcast_update_to` works in a web socket, so the context won't be the same

Comment: how I can get current_user in broadcast_update_to ?

Comment: Try passing it as a parameter to `users_in_room_list`

Comment: How if this method is only run in broadcast_update_to ?

Comment: I have only this solution: add action for update in controller to view and by JS run it in some interval ... it's very messy :)

Answer (score 0):

your **Current.user is nil (meaning has no content)**

if you ask user_name =  User.find_by(Current.user) this statement resulting one user you can try this code

```rb
  x = nil
  user_name = User.find_by(x)
  # this will run query as follow
  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

edit 2:

following your previous question your source code

```rb
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    before_action :set_current_user, if: :user_signed_in?

    private 
    
    def set_current_user
        Current.user = current_user
      # this variable current_user is nil
      # that's why your Current.user = nil
    end

  end
```

Comment: wow I know what it means ... I ask why it's nil if in second line it isnt

Comment: check my edit 2 answer

Comment: it can't be nil ... how current_user can be nil if it's not in every other place? and if it's nil then why user_name = User.find_by(Current.user) return User ?

Comment: you can double check with debugging code on that location that I marked my note

Comment: def set_current_user
        Current.user = current_user
        Rails.logger.fatal "CHECK CURRENT USER #{current_user}"
end

CHECK CURRENT USER - #<User:0x00007f5130fbfdf0>

Comment: Ok, Current.user. has the content from current_user which is not nil but if you want to call Current.user from other class you should put helper_method inside ApplicationController

Comment: no ... helper_method method is used to make a controller method available as a view helper method, not model